# How to join from another table based on the highest value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have two tables with the following data:

**TableA**

```
**ID** | **Item**  
1 | Hat  
2 | Coat  
3 | Jacket
```

**TableB**

```
**ID** | **TableA ID** | **Store** | **Quantity**  
1 | 1 | A | 3  
2 | 1 | B | 2  
3 | 1 | C | 1  
4 | 2 | A | 2  
5 | 2 | B | 4  
6 | 2 | C | 3  
7 | 3 | A | 1  
8 | 3 | B | 2  
9 | 3 | C | 6
```

I am trying to join the two tables with TableA.ID, TableA.Item,TableB.Store as the three returned columns. However I only want to show the Store (A, B or C in this example) with the highest 'quantity' value.
E.g. the end result of the query would look like:

```
**TableA.ID** | **TableA.Item** | **TableB.Store**  
1 | Hat | A  
2 | Coat | B  
3 | Jacket | C
```

Comment: It would be best if you posted some code that you tried before posting here and asking for the full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple using `row_number()`:

```
select a.id, a.item, b.store
from a join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by tableaid order by quantity desc) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on a.id = b.tableaid
where b.seqnum = 1;
```

I can add that it can be more efficient to use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*, b.shop
from a cross apply
     (select top 1 b.*
      from b
      where a.id = b.tableaid
      order by b.quantity desc
     ) b;
```

Both queries can take advantage of an index on `b(tableaid, quantity)`.

Comment: That's great - much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forware using [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
select * 
from ( select * 
            , row_number() over (partition by [TableA ID] order by Quantity desc) as tn 
       from tableA a 
       join tableB b 
         on a.ID = b.[TableA ID]
     )  tt 
where tt.rn = 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.